# Asp.net MVC Controller to accept value or null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult mycontroller(int status, DateTime start, DateTime end) 
{
   ...stuff
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
http://localhost:22200/mycontroller?status=1&start=18/03/2015&end=18/04/2015
```

However, half the time I need to call it like this:

```
http://localhost:22200/mycontroller?status=1
```

I would like to use same controller for both calls.

Is there way to change the controller to accept or not the parameters?

Ps: I don't want to have 2 controllers or a url like this

```
http://localhost:22200/mycontroller?status=1&start=null&end=null
```

Any help out there? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make the `start` and `end` parameters `DateTime?` (nullable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make `start` and `end` optional/nullable parameters as illustrated below.

`ActionResult Action(int status, DateTime? start = null, DateTime? end = null)`

The optional parameters will allow for the action to be called regardless of whether or not the `start` and `end` query string arguments are specified. When omitted, the default value `null` will be used. Thus both of the following URLs will be valid:

> http://localhost:22200/mycontroller?status=1
>
> http://localhost:22200/mycontroller?status=1&start=18/03/2015&end=18/04/2015

Comment: FYI, the default `= null` is not necessary. The necessary one is the nullable parameter `DateTime?` instead of non-nullable `DateTime`.